# Warn User If any value is not Numeric in shell script

Tags: shell, git-bash

I am learning bash.

I would like to do simple script that if user enter values and form that values any of value or values not numeric than warn the user that this value/s not numeric and than sort them and just print the count of numeric values

Thanks.
This is for checking not a numeric value.

```
for((i=0;i<count;i++))
    do
        if ! [ "${ARRAY[i]}" -eq "${ARRAY[i]}" ] 2> /dev/null
            then
                echo "${ARRAY[i]} is not numeric"   
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not elaborate on the types of numeric being tested or perhaps needing validation.
Nevertheless you may consider `printf` evaluations for the numeric types of interest similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARRAY=( 1.1 A 99 'string' '102' ) ; # Mixed array type
for item in ${ARRAY[@]} ; do
    NaN=0 ;
    if ! printf %d "$item" 2>/dev/null ; then NaN=$((++NaN)) ; else printf "%d is decimal\n" "$item" ; continue ; fi ;
    if ! printf %f "$item" 2>/dev/null ; then NaN=$((++NaN)) ; else printf "%f is float\n" "$item" ; continue ; fi ;
    if ! printf %i "$item" 2>/dev/null ; then NaN=$((++NaN)) ; else printf "%i is integer\n" "$item" ; continue ; fi ;
    if  ((NaN != 0)) ; then echo "$item NOT-A-NUMBER" ; fi ;
done ;
```

[`printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) manual / help pages detail all available types which you can extend to the above example.

Comment: Here is the return of your script: `11.1000001.100000 is float
00.0000000A NOT-A-NUMBER
9999 is decimal
00.0000000string NOT-A-NUMBER
102102 is decimal`.
Apart for the fact that this is ugly, you missed the point that `%d` in `printf` in only for integers and do not work for decimals like 1.1.